# jQuery Recursive logic tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is, how do we make the following logic work in jQuery. I start out with this snippet on my HTML page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
</ul>
```

Functionality:

So when I click on the link, I want to check if the

has a child  class. If it     does, then append `<li><a href="#">Child</a></li>` to that child `<ul` element, after the `<a>` tag.     However, if no child `<ul>` is found, it must first create a `<ul>`tag and then add  `<li><a     href="#">Child</a></li>` to that newly created `<ul>` tag.

So clicking on the above example snipped should give this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And clicking on the Parent  tag a second time would give this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also:

My trouble is that I want this to happen recursively. Meaning, clicking on the "Child" text would check if the child `<li>` class has a sub `<ul>` and adds `<li>` to that..if not, adds `<ul>` first and then `<li>`. This should go on till forever.

Here is what I tried — http://jsfiddle.net/arsalanbashir/et79cuj5/

**EDIT** — Just noticed, my code doesn't work at all. No idea why. This is what I did:

```
$('#intro').click(function(){
    if($($('#list').length)){
        $('#list').append("<li><a>SOMETHING</a></li>");
    } else{
        $('.node').append("<ul id='#list'><li><a>SOMETHING</a></li></ul>");
    }
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="node">
        <a id="intro" href="#">Introduction</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit 2** Let me clarify what I was looking for —

A list that adds a child to every element that is clicked upon.

Comment: your code doesn't have an element with id of 'list'

Comment: your if that checks the length is bad syntax... change to $('#list).length

Comment: what does `go on forever` mean. Show expected results. The code you have doesn't come close to doing what you are describing , it doesn't even match your html. Also you can't repeat ID's in a page

Comment: You also need to learn to check for errors `$('#list'.length)` is invalid syntax that will throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine.

```
var add_child = function (element) {
    if($(element).parent().find("ul").html()){
        $(element).parent().find("ul").first().append("<li><a href='#'>Child</a></li>");
    } else{
        $(element).parent().append("<ul><li><a href='#'>Child</a></li><ul>");
    }
}

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    add_child(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#intro').click(function(){
    console.log('clicking');
    if($('#list').length){
        $('#list').append("<li><a>SOMETHING</a></li>");
                 }else{
        $('.node').append("<ul id='#list'><li><a>SOMETHING</a></li></>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using `.children()` in jQuery. This will work recursively, because it checks for children relatively.

```
$('li').click(function () {
    // Check if an inner list exists
    if ($(this).children('ul').length) {
        $(this).children('ul').first().append(child)
    }    
    else {
        $(this).append(newList)
    }
});
```

Comment: This works well, for the first iteration. Example – clicking on "Introduction" thrice gives this — 

- Introduction:
    - Something
    - Something
    - Something

But clicking on "Something" just adds another "Something" to the already existing ones. I want it to make a new "ul" tag inside the "Something" that was clicked on, and add "Something" to it.

Answer (score 0):

see fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/et79cuj5/33/

```
$('#intro').on('click', function () {
    var hasNestedList = $(this).parents('li').has('ul');
    var parentItem = $(this).parents('li');
    var newChildItem = '<li><a href="#">Child</a></li>';
    var newChildList = '<ul></ul>'
    var insertionPoint = parentItem

    if (hasNestedList.size() === 0) {
        parentItem.append(newChildList);
    }
    insertionPoint = $(this).parents('li').find('ul');
    insertionPoint.append(newChildItem)
});
```